# Cheap Pottery Refractory Material

Tags: ceramics, pottery, kiln

I am trying to build an electric kiln for firing pottery, so I need a really high temperature. I intend to use kanthanal wire for the heating element. The problem I am facing is the refractory material. Pottery is just a hobby which I want to explore, so my budget is *incredibly* small. And refractory/fire bricks can be quite expensive in the quantity that I would need. Is there a way to make my own refractory cement that would be as resistant to heat as a fire brick. If so, should I shape the refractory into a brick and then mortar them together or should I make it one solid piece: is there anything gained from having individual bricks.

Comment: Do you have a pottery workshop or highschool / university that offers pottery classes nearby? It would probably be easier to pay a small fee for them to fire your pottery than making your own killn.

Comment: You could use ceramic fibre, the stuff invented to go on the bottom of the space shuttle.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpzS_L3ueeo